# Windows 10 grub entry broken after installing Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, 22.04, grub-efi

I installed Windows 10. It worked. After that I installed Ubuntu 22.04. Now Ubuntu 22.04 works but when I select the Windows 10 grub entry and enter I get the error

```
Setting partition type to 0x7
error: can't find command 'drivemap'.
error: invalid EFI file path.
```

I tried to fix this problem with running `boot-repair` from a live Ubuntu USB stick  but I still get the same errors.

This is what my `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` looks like:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${initrdfail}" = 2 ]; then
   set initrdfail=
elif [ "${initrdfail}" = 1 ]; then
   set next_entry="${prev_entry}"
   set prev_entry=
   save_env prev_entry
   if [ "${next_entry}" ]; then
      set initrdfail=2
   fi
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function initrdfail {
    if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -n "${partuuid}" ]; then
      if [ -z "${initrdfail}" ]; then
        set initrdfail=1
        if [ -n "${boot_once}" ]; then
          set prev_entry="${default}"
          save_env prev_entry
        fi
      fi
      save_env initrdfail
    fi; fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos6'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=10
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if [ ${grub_platform} != pc ]; then
      set linux_gfx_mode=keep
    elif hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos6'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-30-generic root=UUID=b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-30-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-30-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.15.0-30-generic-advanced-b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.15.0-30-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-30-generic root=UUID=b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-30-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-30-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.15.0-30-generic-recovery-b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.15.0-30-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-30-generic root=UUID=b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-30-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-25-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.15.0-25-generic-advanced-b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.15.0-25-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-25-generic root=UUID=b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-25-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-25-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.15.0-25-generic-recovery-b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.15.0-25-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-25-generic root=UUID=b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-25-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+.elf)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos6'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e
    fi
    knetbsd /boot/memtest86+.elf
}
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+.bin, serial console)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos6'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b9ddda50-0ed0-46b6-95b8-959296774f3e
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows 10 (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-58D66EEFD66ECCB6' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  58D66EEFD66ECCB6
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 58D66EEFD66ECCB6
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/35_fwupd ###
### END /etc/grub.d/35_fwupd ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Comment: Boot Repair can't repair Windows bootloaders. The first troubleshooting step in a case like this is NEVER Boot Repair. What you should do is boot Windows directly (UEFI settings > Boot menu). If it works make sure you let it install all the pending updates and disable Fast Startup and shutdown. Then change the boot order back to Ubuntu, boot Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Be sure Ubuntu is installed in the same mode (UEFI vs. legacy) as Windows.  Look at the chainloader path in /boot/g;rub/grub.cfg.  -1 is invalid for UEFI, but that's what legacy uses.

Comment: @ChanganAuto. Do you mean the F11 boot menu with UEFI settings > Boot menu? The F11 menu does not have a Windows entry in my case.

Comment: @ubfan1 I believe I installed both in Legacy mode by selecting `USB:` and not `UEFI USB:` in the F11 boot menu with the Windows and Ubuntu install USB sticks. I could not find the value `-1` anywhere in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Is it perhaps handy if I post my `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file?

Comment: If so there's exactly where your problem starts. Legacy ("BIOS") mode is for computers with BIOS so, from a decade ago.

Comment: @ChanganAuto. Are you saying I have to completely reinstall both OSs using UEFI USB just to solve this startup problem?

Comment: Oops,type.  -1 should have been +1, and from your grub.cfg posting, the line "chainloader +1" on the Windows load is a sure indicator of legacy mode for the Ubuntu which created the grub.cfg file (not valid to determine which mode Windows is in). GPT partitioning on the disk is a sure indicator of a UEFI Windows install, and MSDOS partitioning for legacy. Check the disk partitioning type, if Win is GPT=UEFI, then just figure out how to install Ubuntu in UEFI. If Win is legacy, I recommend reinstalling in UEFI mode (change disk to GPT).

Comment: @Adriaan At least you'll have to reinstall the Windows bootloader in place of Grub and then reinstall Grub (Legacy) in place of Windows. That's one of the inconveniences of the old BIOS/MBR ("msdos") based mode. Understand that (1) Windows 11 no longer allows this, it can only be installed in UEFI mode; (2) Legacy/CSM exists (and largely overstayed its welcome) because a certain very used old Windows version din't support anything else (said version being now obsolete for so many years there's absolutely no reason to keep CSM at the firmware level, very soon it won't be an option) (...)

Comment: (...) (3) All current hardware is designed to work with OSes in UEFI mode and the insistence on Legacy ("BIOS") may have undesirable and unpredictable effects in hardware initialization (as I use to say when troubleshooting weird graphical issues, GPUs that don't work properly when they should, etc., knowing the user installed in Legacy then "all bets are off"). So, yes, although you don't have to, installing both OSes in the proper UEFI mode is strongly recommended (and forgot about the remnant of a bygone era that officially ended in 2012 when Microsoft "mandated" manufacturers (...)

Comment: (...) to factory install the then Windows 8 in UEFI mode and GPT drives). History lesson apart, the rule for multi-booting is always install OSes in the same mode. But keep in  mind that when something like this happens you'll need to reinstall bootloaders one after the other to correct boot issues in BIOS/Legacy with MBR because only one bootloader is supported at any given time.

Comment: Just reinstalling Ubuntu 22.04 with UEFI USB didn't fix the Windows bootloader. Reinstalling first Windows 10 with UEFI USB and then Ubuntu 22.04 with UEFI USB did fix the Windows bootloader. Now, both OSs are booting properly.